# Subprocess Isolation in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, chroot, isolation

I am currently working on a personal project where I have to run two processes simultaneously. The problem is that I have to isolate each of them (they cannot communicate between them or with my system) and I must be able to control their stdin, stdout and stderr. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module..

Comment: If you need a measure of isolation between each other and the system, you would need to run each of them in a container. You may want to look at Docker.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have an objection to using a 3'rd party communication library for your task but this sounds like what ZeroMQ would be used for.